# Why do I get "404 Not Found" and "Failed to change directory" errors when I try to install a Perl module with cpan?

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

I tried to install `Capture::Tiny` with this command:

```
cpan Capture/Tiny
```

But the installation fails with the following output:

```
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 25 May 2016 08:17:02 GMT
Running make for C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
HTTP::Tiny failed with code[404] message[Not Found]
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.gz
HTTP::Tiny failed with code[404] message[Not Found]

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548"
to get
    http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
--2016-05-25 21:07:02--  http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
Resolving mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)... 130.225.254.116, 2001:878:346::116
Connecting to mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)|130.225.254.116|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-05-25 21:07:02 ERROR 404: Not Found.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548" "http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548'. Giving up on it.
Fetching with Net::FTP:
ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
  Couldn't cwd cpan/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture: Failed to change directory.

Fetching with Net::FTP
ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.gz
  Couldn't cwd cpan/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture: Failed to change directory.


Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548"
to get
    ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
--2016-05-25 21:07:03--  ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
           => ‘/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548’
Resolving mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)... 130.225.254.116, 2001:878:346::116
Connecting to mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)|130.225.254.116|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture ... 
No such directory ‘cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture’.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548" "ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548'. Giving up on it.

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548"
to get
    http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
--2016-05-25 21:07:03--  http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
Resolving mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)... 130.225.254.116, 2001:878:346::116
Connecting to mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)|130.225.254.116|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-05-25 21:07:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548" "http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548 with size 0

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548"
to get
    ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
--2016-05-25 21:07:03--  ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
           => ‘/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548’
Resolving mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)... 130.225.254.116, 2001:878:346::116
Connecting to mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)|130.225.254.116|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture ... 
No such directory ‘cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture’.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548" "ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548'. Giving up on it.
No external ftp command available

Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
HTTP::Tiny failed with code[404] message[Not Found]
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.gz
HTTP::Tiny failed with code[404] message[Not Found]

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548"
to get
    http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
--2016-05-25 21:07:03--  http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
Resolving mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)... 130.225.254.116, 2001:878:346::116
Connecting to mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)|130.225.254.116|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-05-25 21:07:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548" "http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548'. Giving up on it.

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548"
to get
    http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
--2016-05-25 21:07:03--  http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
Resolving mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)... 130.225.254.116, 2001:878:346::116
Connecting to mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)|130.225.254.116|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-05-25 21:07:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548" "http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548'. Giving up on it.
Fetching with Net::FTP:
ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
  Couldn't cwd cpan/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture: Failed to change directory.

Fetching with Net::FTP
ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.gz
  Couldn't cwd cpan/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture: Failed to change directory.


Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548"
to get
    ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
--2016-05-25 21:07:03--  ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
           => ‘/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548’
Resolving mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)... 130.225.254.116, 2001:878:346::116
Connecting to mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)|130.225.254.116|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture ... 
No such directory ‘cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture’.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548" "ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548'. Giving up on it.

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548"
to get
    ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
--2016-05-25 21:07:03--  ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
           => ‘/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548’
Resolving mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)... 130.225.254.116, 2001:878:346::116
Connecting to mirrors.dotsrc.org (mirrors.dotsrc.org)|130.225.254.116|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture ... 
No such directory ‘cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture’.


    Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548" "ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny" ")
    returned status 8 (wstat 2048), left
/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548 with size 0
    Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/C/C/Ca/Capture/Tiny.tmp1548'. Giving up on it.
No external ftp command available

Please check, if the URLs I found in your configuration file
(http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/, ftp://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cpan/) are
valid. The urllist can be edited. E.g. with 'o conf urllist push
ftp://myurl/'

Could not fetch authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny
```

I've tried multiple mirrors but they all give the same errors. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you download the distribution manually from [here](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.40.tar.gz), and then run `cpanm Capture-Tiny-0.40.tar.gz`?

Comment: Strange that it's looking for `authors/id/C/C//C/Ca/Capture/Tiny`, it should be `authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/`. Does this happen for every mirror you've tried?

Comment: Good point, @ThisSuitIsBlackNot! I just noticed that the OP is using `cpan Capture/Tiny`, and not `cpan Capture::Tiny`, which causes that issue

Comment: @stevieb \*facepalm\* Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the DAGOLDEN piece ;)

Comment: I will never do that mistake again =)

Comment: On Ubuntu and Linux Mint (and probably other distributions), it's available as a package: `sudo apt-get install libcapture-tiny-perl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ran:

```
cpan Capture/Tiny
#           ^-- notice the slash
```

The slash tells `cpan` to look for the distribution file at the specified path. In this case, `cpan` searches for the distribution file `Tiny` by author `Capture`. This doesn't exist, so the download fails.

Passing a path (`Foo/Bar`) instead of a module name (`Foo::Bar`) lets you [install a specific version](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN#The-four-CPAN::-Classes:-Author-Bundle-Module-Distribution) of a distribution. To install [Capture-Tiny-0.41-TRIAL](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.41-TRIAL.tar.gz), which is a development version, you would run:

```
cpan DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.41-TRIAL.tar.gz
```

But you probably just wanted to install the latest non-development version of Capture::Tiny, so you should run:

```
cpan Capture::Tiny
```

Answer (score 8):

Try changing your command from `cpan Capture/Tiny` to `cpan Capture::Tiny`. If that fails, download the tarball from [here](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/Capture-Tiny-0.40.tar.gz), and then run `cpanm Capture-Tiny-0.40.tar.gz`